# Find mean anomaly knowing true anomaly?

Tags: astronomy, orbital-motion

I know how to find the true anomaly by knowing the eccentric anomaly and finding eccentric anomaly by knowing the mean anomaly. 
M >> E >> True anomaly ... ok.

But how to find anomaly eccentric  and mean anomaly , only knowing true anomaly?
True anomaly >> E >> M ? (inverse)

Anomaly of planetary orbits and Kepler's formulas

Comment: What do you mean by "anomaly"? Can you please provide more context?

Comment: Where you looking for [Find true anomaly given period, eccentricity and time](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6789/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is quite straightforward. If you have the true anomaly $\nu$, then the eccentric anomaly $E$ is found from
$$\tan \frac{E(t)}{2} = \left(\frac{1+e}{1-e}\right)^{-1/2} \tan \frac{\nu(t)}{2},$$
where $e$ is the eccentricity.

Then you use Kepler's equation to find the mean anomaly $M$
$$M(t) = E(t) - e \sin E(t).$$

Comment: (t) the time since passing through the perielium I do not have.

Comment: @SidneyScholze $\nu(t)$ means $\nu$ as a function of time. Time can be measured from any zero point.