# Kepler orbit from mass, period, and eccentricity

Tags: orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I want to calculate the Keplerian orbital elements in the central force case.

Given the mass M of the "sun" in kg, the eccentricity $e$ of the orbit, and the period $T$ in seconds, I believe that is sufficient to calculate the rest of the parameters (provided we make assumptions of convenience, e.g. $\theta=0$ at $t=0$ and our coordinate system is in the plane of the orbit).

I haven't been able to figure out how to get the rest of the parameters from the equations. Ultimately I want to calculate Cartesian position and velocity at any given time. How do I get from $(M,e,T)$ to the other parameters?

Comment: And you are also defining the longitude of perihelion in some way?

Comment: Doesn't this answer the question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6789/find-true-anomaly-given-period-eccentricity-and-time  You basically have to solve the Kepler equation.

Comment: BTW, You should avoid using G, since its value is only known to around 5 digits. Instead, use solar masses. See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/48616/16685 Another option for simple Kepler orbits is "natural" units, such that the semi-major axis and period are 1, which means $GM=4\pi^2$

Comment: What "other parameters" are you talking about? As ProfRob said, you need to *specify* the orientation of the ellipse, somehow. Presumably, you know how to calculate `a` from `T` and `GM`.